# "This post has been edited" bugs

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, notification-bar

I'm writing an edit to an answer. I get the little blue bar that says "This post has been edited 1 time since you began. Your edit can only be saved if it is more thorough than the currently saved edit."

[image]

Now, I clicked the link in the bar which took me to the revision history on the *question* (I was editing an answer, remember). Now, first of all, the question hasn't been edited in two hours (and I have not been editing even a quarter of an hour). But, neither has the answer been edited in the last two hours!

[image]

Then, of course I hit the "[An edit has been made .. Looping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158186/192187)" bug when I hit the X button (which drives me crazy).

I am using chrome 25.0.1364.97 on Windows 7.

Comment: Reproduced. I saw it today while working on *[this revision](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/142963/6)* (of an answer), but *only* for that one. It appeared after some time (1-2 minutes?) after starting the editing. It said: "... edited 4 times ..." (!).

Comment: yes, I had this today also. Was editing an answer to a recently edited question (a common enough thing) and got the notification. Ignored it, since this is my answer dammit, and it saved fine. I believe I was being notified about the question - no-one else was trying to edit my answer. On Workplace IIRC.

Comment: Had this happen today several times on meta.

Comment: Reproduced - it appears to happen when editing *any answer* that's been posted (or more likely most recently edited) **before** the most recent edit to the *question*. After typing something, it takes about 45 seconds to appear.

Comment: Happens to me but with the [old-style top-bar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170013/147333)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is using the wrong id (the question's id) in the heart-beat. This has been rectified in the next build. Sorry 'bout that.

So: even though you were editing an answer, that message related to tweaks to the question.