# Old style topbar appears when editing

Tags: bug, edits, top-bar

When editing [a post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15198439/488657), a few seconds after I began editing the good old topbar appeared saying "this post has been edited 1 time".

It's very disturbing. I canceled my edit thinking of a concurrent edit from another user, but it's not the case.

[image]