# Is there interest in adding a "visual glossary" to the glossary wiki (so we can better know the names of things when we discuss them)

Tags: discussion

I have been in several discussions/exchanges about SE that have been severely impeded because we spent much time and energy trying to figure out what *literally* each other was talking about.

We didn't have a shared set of names for anything, so we would either make up descriptive names, sometimes based on appearance (e.g. that red circle with the number in it = "inbox notification"?) or a notification that the post on the page you're looking at is being edited, or the notification on the main question page that a new question has been asked or an edit has been made.

Is there interest in adding a place where we can look up the actual SE names of visual elements on pages and site functionalities without already knowing their names?

Based on several comments below, perhaps adding it to the community wiki [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/303080)?

One option are a few annotated screenshots with perhaps little numbers and a table below with the numbers and the corresponding name, and perhaps even link to the line in the *alphabetical* glossary.

But perhaps a *better option* mentioned by @Rob [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1265023) might be for small images (e.g. [image: screenshot of an inbox notification] or [image: screenshot of notification]) to appear with or alongside the definitions in the existing glossary wiki.

This would add functionality and utility to the wiki because now even if you don't know the official name of what you are looking for you can still find it and it's name and description.

This can enhance our ability to have *a shared set of names* for things which may help  advanced users and beginners alike to communicate about the site's workings amongst themselves and each other.

---

@Rob [points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1265064) that visual glossaries are definitely a thing:

- [What do you call a glossary accompanied with visuals?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/285661/217285)
- [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/194363/217285) to "What is a catalog of images and their description called?" (spoiler alert: *visual glossary*)

Comment: The first hit when you type glossary in search is: [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)

Comment: @Luuklag neither "post notice" nor "tooltips" nor "inbox notification" is there, my three examples. In fact, there's nothing there about "the various items on pages and site functionalities" that I can find at all.

Comment: You're free to add them there. Your question is if there was a glossary, then answer is: Yes there is.

Comment: @Luuklag take a look at the title of my question: "Is there a place where I can look up the actual SE names of the various items on pages and site functionalities? Is there an SE glossary?" You have to ignore 75% of the title for your complaint to be valid.

Comment: FWIW, I *just* added Post Notice in there, since it's definitely not a term that's self-explanatory if you're unfamiliar with the site's workings.

Comment: @Spevacus Oh, in case you might know, what are those messages called when a post has been edited on the page you are looking at that say you should refresh the page to see the changes?

Comment: I would say those are probably "notifications" in the [notification bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/notification-bar/info) (example question about it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169948/). The term used for them seems to vary, but they do differ from the term used for "Inbox notifications" (notifications over your actual inbox) and "Review indicators" (the little red dot by a review queue icon that indicates if there are items that need review).

Comment: @uhoh no specfic name to those afaik, they're just real time messages.

Comment: @Spevacus oh that's one kind, when you are also editing, but there's another kind when you are just viewing a page.

Comment: Answer posts have now been prevented. I'm not seeing how that's the best of all possible outcomes here.

Comment: Well, I kinda agree with the duplicate closure. You asked if we had a glossary, and we pointed you to it. That it's not sufficient isn't great but, if there are missing terms that need added, you can help add them.

Comment: @Spevacus I asked  "Is there a place where I can look up the actual SE names of the various items on pages and site functionalities?  Is there an SE glossary?" You have to ignore 75% of the title for your complaint to be valid. Each time you post an inaccurate/misleading comment I'll correct it.

Comment: I didn't ignore 75% of the title. The question this is closed as a duplicate of is the place we store that information. If the information you want is missing from it, it's best to add it there than here as an answer.

Comment: @Spevacus that place is not for storing "the actual SE names of the various items on pages and site functionalities". It's not an answer to my question. It's that 75% of my title you keep omitting.

Comment: @Spevacus To add clarification to this question this is around the new activity notice that appears on the main page of a site such as "3 questions with new activity" and adding (3) to the title bar. For some reason uhoh is under the belief that it doesn't count as a notification. This was brought up in a meta question about the number of edits that are acceptable on in a short amount of time after it has been posted. https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6268/how-many-edits-can-politics-se-handle-on-a-single-question/

Comment: @JoeW no do not redefine my question as something else. I'm the OP, I do the clarifications. Link is fine but don't confuse folks by hijacking my question for your own purposes.

Comment: *That isn't a place to list "the actual SE names of the various items on pages and site functionalities"* - wrong. It is. And if there is a new term, it can/should be added there.

Comment: @uhoh I am providing details on what is the source of the question which is not mentioned at all in this question. In the related question you are objecting to me calling the new activity a notification and I am just providing that detail on this question.

Comment: BTW, "tooltip" isn't just local SE terminology, it's a general GUI term (with a couple of synonyms) that long predates SE. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooltip

Comment: @PM2Ring there are almost 200 different SE communities, they all use the site and vote up and down and may want to discuss how the site works using words, but *most of us are not web programmers* so I don't see how that's helpful or relevant.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar if/when the question is reopened that can be posted as an answer and voted upon by the community. Those answers are listed alphabetically, you have to already know the name of something to find the definition there. If you don't know the name you have to read through every single definition to see if something fits, and even then you can't be certain. What I have asked for here is a way to find the names of things for which we do not know the names. So... no it is not.

Comment: I think your question is ok. It would be great if SE terminology were better documented. Also, I think that the SE interface in general isn't well-documented: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418169/rule-proposal-comments-asking-for-accepts-and-votes-shall-no-longer-be-allowed/418202#comment911308_418202 OTOH, I don't think you *need* to be a GUI programmer to know that tooltips are called that, and my main point previously was that "tooltip" isn't local Stack Exchange jargon, it's a standard term whose meaning can be found in external references.

Comment: @PM2Ring "can be found" so imagine a normal person who asks a few cooking and DIY questions trying to find out the name of the message that appears when their cursor hovers over the up and down vote arrows. With zero experience with web page design, where exactly are they going to go to find its technical name? We don't exclude information from SE that can be found in external references, we do *the exact opposite* we bring together information from external sources! Imagine if we deleted all your answers that draw from external sources!

Comment: Do we also need to tell them what menu, icon, window, title bar, mouse, etc, mean? Maybe we should have a complete (illustrated) dictionary...

Comment: @PM2Ring again I don't see how that's a helpful comment here. Every resource is finite, you start with the most important and relevant items.

Comment: I don't think most people really care what the name of the text that appears when you hover over something is.

Comment: You would need to define what "the actual SE name of visual elements" means. If it means "the technical name that is used on a page" then this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/rschrieken/6499f4bdf1a57e89a9259aa367219d54) with both a javascript discovery function and its result for this very page could be a starting point. Here is the reasoning: Most of the visual elements that need some interaction are tagged with a `js-*` classname so the javascript can bind events (like mouse click) to those elements. I imagine with this knowledge you can find and annotate these for reference later.

Comment: @rene I think my question makes it fairly clear that I'm looking for names that we can use to discuss them within Stack Exchange - to ask questions about them or to report problems for example. That seems like a pretty obvious choice.

Comment: @uhoh I understand that *you* don't think it's a duplicate of the glossary post, but it is, as things currently exist on the site. Arguing that it's not, is basically arguing for information fragmentation, which makes SE sites **much** harder to use, because it makes finding information (and organizing, updating, etc.) much, much harder both for users looking for information and people trying to maintain it.

Comment: It could be argued we should have a *separate* glossary of terms which are just about the elements of the SE UI, what SE calls them, and/or what they are generally called in the industry. There will be *considerable* overlap between such a new glossary and the already existing one. If we should have such a separate glossary here on MSE is something which would be reasonable to discuss, but that should be done on a Q&A which is designed and focused on *specifically discussing how the information should be organized*, not as a side issue on a post which is specifically asking for information.

Comment: In addition to [Makyen's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378998/is-there-a-place-where-i-can-look-up-the-actual-se-names-of-visual-elements-on-p#comment1265013_378998) the "visual" version (images) should appear **alongside** the textual description - basically you are mentioning that we already have a simple textual version, and suggesting that we should add another glossary that is both textual and visual; why not simply add images to the existing glossary? --- You should **ask** to change this point: "Keep it very, very brief, terse, and to the point", allowing images.

Comment: @Rob I've only asked "Is there a place..." I'll defer to the community to decide where that place might be.

Comment: Due to the fair duplicate suggestion, and the upvotes on the comment, that's the place or the answer is "no"; take your pick. As a [tag:discussion] tagged question you can edit to ask what people think of the proposal or wait for the review to complete.

Comment: PS: My [reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/82879) is: "Needs details or clarity - This question should include more details and clarify the problem.", which is a vague suggestion to make the edit proposed in the above comment. The other reviewer suggests closing as a duplicate, which I *would* agree with; if you don't plan to rescue your question.

Comment: @Rob it's 7:30 AM here and my coffee has not yet kicked in, and for that reason I don't fully understand what you are saying yet. I have a hunch you're proposing something very helpful, I just can't quite wrap my mind around it.

Comment: @Rob okay, if I try to paraphrase; it looks like there's no interest in a *new location* for a place to 'look up the actual SE names of visual elements on pages and site functionalities' but *might be* some interest in adding such a feature to the SE glossary, and asking more specifically about that and focusing on the need for it and what it might look like might be a better question, and in this case closing this question (not deleting it) and perhaps then taking some time to formulate a higher quality and more focused new question along those lines might be a good way forward. Is that it?

Comment: @Rob or at least is that consistent and/or compatible with what you're recommending?

Comment: In answer to your 2nd to last comment, yes. Searching for [this](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=visual+glossary) I find:  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285661/what-do-you-call-a-glossary-accompanied-with-visuals  
and  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193921/what-is-a-catalog-of-images-and-their-description-called/194363#194363 - due to the near equal votes and lack of an answer I think you can get away with simply editing, as opposed to waiting for it to close and then attempting to edit (possibly with an answer); as a new question seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Rob how does this look?

Comment: I think that you'd be best off agreeing that this is a duplicate to what Makyen suggested; you can do that with one vote. --- Then follow the instructions in the final paragraph there, and write a new answer; linking to this question. --- "Add a new answer if you believe a new issue is likely to come up repeatedly. For instance, discussion about what terms to include, whether the glossary should be broken up to make linking easier, or formatting issues might be best discussed in new answer/comment posts.".

Comment: @Rob I just finished the edit here, and I think I understand what you're saying. Yes I agree and I'll likely do all of that within another canonical hour. I'll try to close now... success!

Comment: @Rob it took guts and courage, but I've just added an answer there.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_C._Blesse#Further_reading - now to flag and ask the moderator to move **all** the comments to chat.

Comment: @Rob That's interesting, since the post is closed (and will likely stay that way) isn't it better to keep the discussion here for a little while at least? Doesn't quick (re)moval of the comments right now sort-of pull the rug out from under my "based on Rob's comment... and some positive feedback there"?  Is there urgency to move these to chat right now? I understand they'll still be available in chat, but what harm are the comments doing in the location where they have been made? (just trying to better understand "SE theory")

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=move%20to%20chat - especially the first hit. Up to you, I was just thinking of them getting a constant stream of flags from 10 comments ago.

Comment: I have to note that we already *have* a glossary for how SE calls their visual elements - "components" (notices, tooltips, action buttons, modals, you name it) are documented in detail on the official website of [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/using-stacks/). I think this is what you might be looking for.

Comment: [That's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378998/is-there-interest-in-adding-a-visual-glossary-to-the-glossary-wiki-so-we-can?noredirect=1#comment1265086_378998) really [not related](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Icons) to the answer.